# How to Convert Ruby UTF String

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

I have some string data, looks like this:

```
"\x00M\x00o\x00d\x00e\x00l\x00"
```

When I run:

```
puts "\x00M\x00o\x00d\x00e\x00l\x00"
```

I see what I like:

```
'Model'
```

But as I understand, this string is still encoded differently. puts seems to apply some translation.

I'd like to convert "\x00M\x00o\x00d\x00e\x00l\x00" into 'Model' for use elsewhere, where the strangely encoded string doesn't work for me.

Anyone know a way to do this? I've searched my eyeballs out.

Comment: This is encoded as UTF16-BE, apparently, you are somehow trying to decode it as UTF-8.

Comment: Correct. My conversion attempts seem to not work. But I want it in UTF-8 ASCII

Comment: What about `"\x00M\x00o\x00d\x00e\x00l\x00".gsub("\x00","")`?

Comment: It’s not valid utf-16 at the moment (be or le), it has an extra `\x00` at the start (or end).

Comment: This must be where I'm getting stuck than. @AmitKumarGupta it looks like that will work actually, though it doesn't seem like an ideal solution. I suppose the API giving me this junk data is to blame though. I'll head out on this solution for now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So this was the solution I came to, thanks to those who helped come to this:

```
encoding_options = {
  invalid: :replace,
  undef: :replace,
  replace: '',
  universal_newline: true
}

data.gsub("\x00", '')
  .encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options)
```